# How to do fog effect with AndEngine?

Tags: android, andengine

I wanna to achieve a Fog effect using AndEngine for Android. Just some moving fog over the whole screen and a background sprite that becomes clearer and clearer in the fog and than the fog disappear and the whole screen is clear and the whole background sprite is so beautiful. How can I achieve this effect using Java and AndEngine in Android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since andengine is a 2D framework, this is what you do:
1.Create a sprite that has the fog image. Make that in you favorite graphics program.

2.Use a timerHandler to slowly change the alpha value of the sprite to 0.

1. See the background. I assume its a beautiful, since that's the way you describe it.

Comment: Instead of having a timeHandler, I would suggest using an AlphaModifyer